# iPhone - UIView presented with keyboard - works, but with bug

Tags: iphone, notifications, uikeyboard

I have a UIViewController that has two text fields, `inputA` and `inputB`. `inputA` works like a normal text field, click it and the keyboard shows up and you can type. But `inputB` triggers another view (think of it as a button). This second view, `MyView`, has a custom popup view which is animated to appear with the keyboard. `MyView`'s popup is initially with the alpha to 0 and I have set notifications for when the keyboard shows up to have the popup's view alpha to be set to 1.

This works great, but I have a "bug" where when the keyboard is currently showing because the user tapped inputA first, then they tap inputB, it fires the `MyView` but because the keyboard is already showing the notification isn't sent to change the popup alpha to 1.

So the question: what is the clean way to work around this issue? I want the view to appear along with the keyboard, but if it is already there, it should just be sent.

**Is there a way to test if the keyboard is already showing?** I want to do this without setting a bool value every time the keyboard is shown/hide in those two views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

if ([inputA isFirstResponder] || [inputB isFirstResponder]){

//keyboard is displayed

}else{

//keyboard is not displayed

}

Comment: The problem is that the check needs to happen in a different view, so inputA and inputB are no longer local variables to check. But I guess I could do that with my other view. Do a timer check to see if it is first responder (which it always will be since it is in the loadView) and then fire the function to unhide it. Just wish there was a cleaner way.

Comment: pass the parent object to your new view.  Then you can access the elements in the parent class without any trouble.